# Derivation of formula for probability of union of events

Tags: probability

I am trying to derive the formula for probability of union of three non-exclusive events. I am attaching my derivation.

[image]
But later i found out that it's not matching the actual formula. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your first equation is wrong. Note that, when $A=B=C,$ your formula gives you $P(A\cup A\cup A)=2P(A).$

Answer (score 1):

When you sum $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ and $P(C)$, you end up including $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ three times, so you need to subtract off two copies of $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, not one copy.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the disjoint areas.

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C) ~=~ & \mathsf P(A_0)+\mathsf P(B_0)+\mathsf P(C_0) + \mathsf P(S_1)+\mathsf P(S_2)+\mathsf P(S_3)+\mathsf P(S_\blacktriangle)
\\[2ex] ~=~ &{ \mathsf P(A_0\cup S_1\cup S_2\cup S_\blacktriangle)+\mathsf P(B_0\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_\blacktriangle)+\mathsf P(C_0\cup S_3\cup S_1\cup S_\blacktriangle) \\ - 2\mathsf P(S_1)-2\mathsf P(S_2)-2\mathsf P(S_3)-2\mathsf P(S_\blacktriangle)}\\[2ex] ~=~ &{ \mathsf P(A_0\cup S_1\cup S_2\cup S_\blacktriangle)+\mathsf P(B_0\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_\blacktriangle)+\mathsf P(C_0\cup S_3\cup S_1\cup S_\blacktriangle) \\ - \mathsf P(S_1\cup S_2\cup S_\blacktriangle)-\mathsf P(S_2\cup S_3\cup S_\blacktriangle)-\mathsf P(S_3\cup S_1\cup S_\blacktriangle) \\ +\mathsf P(S_\blacktriangle)} \\[3ex]\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C) ~=~ & \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(C)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap C)-\mathsf P(B\cap C)+\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)\end{align}$

In short: we have one $\blacktriangle$, we add three for each big circle and subtract three for each lens.  That leaves us with just one $\blacktriangle$.

---

Alternatively

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\cup X) ~=~ & \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(X)-\mathsf P(A\cap X)
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C) ~=~ & \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\cup C)-\mathsf P(A\cap(B\cup C))
\\[1ex] ~=~ & \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(C)-\mathsf P(B\cap C)-\mathsf P((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C))
\\[1ex] ~=~ & \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(C)-\mathsf P(B\cap C)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap C)+\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)
\\[2ex]\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C) ~=~ & \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(C)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A\cap C)-\mathsf P(B\cap C)+\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C) 
\end{align}$

---